# How to configure VPN Server in Windows 2008 (without AD, Domain and User Policy)

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to set up a VPN for a small busines that have 3 places to be connected in order to access a database and documents that are in one of the computers. So it means that 2 of the places must see the 3rd one.

I set up a VPS with public IP in cheapwindowsvps.com and I wanted to use LAN routing or VPN Server from Winndows Server 2008 R2, but each time I try I get som edifferent error and each of the Internet tutoriais shows a different way to configure.

I wish I could make a clean, easy and simple configurations of this service where I had no problems for the client computers to set up a VPN connection to this server by only giving a password, that could be the same ofr both or not.

Is there a way to install that VPN without Remote Connection Policy, Active Directories or Domain Names?

*I don't want to use Hamachi, Teamviewer, NeoRouter on any 3rd party services*

Comment: If you won't to use any third party solutions, you can setup L2TP VPN. This [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/710454/how-to-setup-l2tp-ipsec-vpn-server-on-windows-server-2008-r2) may be helpful

Comment: Thank you @alex, I am going to check this solution right now.